Timeout al conectarse a https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/, cuando hago un docker pull:python3.12
Estoy teniendo problemas con Docker y docker compose, ya que al ejecutar por ejemplo docker pull python_3.12 da este error de conexion ""Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"".
Pero cuando hago un curl -v https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ me devuelve esto:
* Host registry-1.docker.io:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2600:1f18:2148:bc02:445d:9ace:d20b:c303, 2600:1f18:2148:bc01:571f:e759:a87a:2961, 2600:1f18:2148:bc00:8d61:9b62:40aa:8bb8
* IPv4: 54.236.113.205, 54.198.86.24, 54.227.20.253
*   Trying 54.236.113.205:443...
* Connected to registry-1.docker.io (54.236.113.205) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 / X25519 / RSASSA-PSS
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.docker.com
*  start date: Sep  2 00:00:00 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Oct  1 23:59:59 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "registry-1.docker.io" matched cert's "*.docker.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 1: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 2: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry-1.docker.io
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*

Que aparentemente se conecta bien a la url. Lo curioso que desde otro equipo si funciona y haciendo el curl me devuelve esto que es igual salvo que al final me devuelve una respuesta mientras que el otro no:
* Host registry-1.docker.io:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2600:1f18:2148:bc02:445d:9ace:d20b:c303, 2600:1f18:2148:bc00:8d61:9b62:40aa:8bb8, 2600:1f18:2148:bc01:571f:e759:a87a:2961
* IPv4: 54.227.20.253, 54.236.113.205, 54.198.86.24
*   Trying 54.227.20.253:443...
* Connected to registry-1.docker.io (54.227.20.253) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 / X25519 / RSASSA-PSS
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.docker.com
*  start date: Sep  2 00:00:00 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Oct  1 23:59:59 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "registry-1.docker.io" matched cert's "*.docker.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 1: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 2: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry-1.docker.io
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< content-type: application/json
< docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
< www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io"
< date: Wed, 11 Dec 2024 13:44:10 GMT
< content-length: 87
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
<
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
* Connection #0 to host registry-1.docker.io left intact

He borrado la cache del docker limpiado contenedores, networks, volumenes e imagenes, he reiniciado el servicio docker y sigue igual, e incluso cambie el daemon.json de docker:
{
  "data-root": "/opt/docker",
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"],
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://registry.docker-cn.com"],
  "debug": true,
  "ipv6": false,
  "max-concurrent-downloads": 3,
  "max-concurrent-uploads": 3,
  "default-address-pools": [
     {
         "base": "192.168.0.0/16",
         "size": 24
     }
   ]
}

Tiene pinta que hay algo de la configuración que se ha cambiado y no deja acceder al dominio para descargar la imagen.
¿Alguien ha tenido este mismo problema?
